# ScrollTo nearest container

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm having a bit of a problem with a site I'm building.
I want an effect that if your in between 2 div's it will auto scroll after the mouse has been stationary for approx. 2 seconds.
An example of this effect can be found on this [site](http://www.tigihairreborn.com) which uses ScrollTo.js to create the effect.

My site uses the same layout with each div container been 1000px. I can use scrollTo.js to click a link to take me too a container, but I want it to detect if its not at the top of a div and scroll to the closest one.

Any information to point me in the correct direction would be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: pseudo code: get current Y > floor / ceil to nearest 1000px > scroll to the value

Comment: Thanks Shivan but I dont quite understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps :

1. get current scroll position's Y value ( save it to a variable named `posY` )
2. calculate the value of the nearest 1000 by `ceil` or `floor` function ( depends on you want to go to next item or previous item )
3. scroll to the value in Step 2

which part you are unclear ?